# MomentJS in production server gives me a different unix timestamp

Tags: javascript, momentjs

please help me to understand where the problem is.
In a form, I can set an alarm, select date and select time. I just want to get the unix timestamp of this date+time selected.

I use momentjs to get the unix timestamp of the date and time selected.

In my computer it works perfectly. 
But in production server the timestamp in seconds is 6 hours back.

This is the piece of js code:

```
var date = jqForm.find("input[name=alert_date]").val();
                        var time = jqForm.find("input[name=alert_time]").val();
                        var datetime = date+' '+time;
                        console.log(datetime);
                        ts_datetime = moment(datetime, "DD/MM/YYYY H:mm").unix();
                        console.log(ts_datetime);
                        options.data = {'ts_datetime' : ts_datetime};
```

Server has the right date and time.

Comment: You do not define a timezone with `moment(datetime, "DD/MM/YYYY H:mm").unix();`.  `[...]By default, moment objects are created in the local time zone. To change the default time zone, use moment.tz.setDefault with a valid time zone.[...]`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your inputs are the same (which you did not provide), then it's likely that you are just seeing the difference between the time zone of your server and the time zone of your machine.

UNIX timestamps are in terms of UTC, but you're calling the `moment` function which, by default, uses the local time zone.

If you intended the input to be in UTC, then you can call `moment.utc(...)` instead.

```
ts_datetime = moment.utc(datetime, "DD/MM/YYYY H:mm").unix();
```